# Why is there a sorting error in this list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have these models in a system for images and image tags:

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // some more properties...

    public List<ImageTag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class ImageTag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

To get a list of the top 10 most used tags, I run this query:

```
List<ImageTag> mostUsedTags =
    await db.Images
        .Select(t => t.Tags.OrderBy(o => o.ImageId).FirstOrDefault()).Take(10)
        .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

// The list has the tags with the fewest images first, so I have to reverse it:
mostUsedTags.Reverse();
```

The list I get has the following number of images associated with them: 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1.

Why has the fourth and fifth place swapped places?

Comment: You're sorting the image tags held by each image before selecting the first one. You are not sorting the images themselves.

Comment: Your classes seem overly tied together, and with some redundent properties. Also, it's not clear how to distinguish which tags are unique. Your `Image` has a list of `ImageTag`, and an `ImageTag` has an `Image` **and** an `ImageId`. This seems like a really poor design, since an `ImageTag` could be added to an `Image.Tags` list, yet the `ImageTag` itself could have a completely different `Image` set on it's `Image` property, and it could also have another completely different `Image.Id` set for it's `ImageId` property.

Comment: What @RufusL said is propably the core issue. My guess is that you had a N:M relationship in your data. ImageTag to Image? That sounds like a classical N:M relationship. N:M's have to be resolved using a intermediate table/type, wich turns it into two 1:N realtionships. Then you can do work with that.

Comment: @RufusL This is pretty standard for EF or EF Core model classes with one-to-many FK relationships, so no concern here. Frameworks use these properties to build SQL queries with joins, and also maintains them consistently when materializing the query results.

Comment: If one of the answers has solved your problem, best mark it as accepted for future reader, if not, you might consider update the question with new information and your new findings and why they don't work, so someone else can answer it

Comment: @MichaelRandall I will, as soon as I have had a chance to try them out. I don't program every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear to me how you determine if a tag is used by more than one image because the mapping between the two classes seems a little "muddy" (as i described in a comment under the question).

But assuming that the `Tag` property is the property we'd use to see if two `ImageTag` objects are the same, then you can do something like this to get the most used tags:

```
var mostUsedTags = images
    .SelectMany(i => i.Tags)           // Get all the ImageTags from all the images
    .GroupBy(t => t.Tag)               // Group them by the Tag property
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()) // Order groups by their count (descending)
    .Take(10)                          // Take the top 10 results
    .Select(g => g.Count());           // Select the count associated with each tag
```

You could also select a string that mentions the `Tag`, so you can tell which tags are the most popular:

```
.Select(g => $"'{g.Key}' is associated with {g.Count()} images");
```

or just replace the `.Select()` with `.ToList()` to get a list of all the `IGrouping` objects themselves, so you have all the data associated with each group

Comment: Thank you. This works. But is there a way to avoid loading up all the `image`s first, and then working on that collection? It's fine now that the database only contains a few images, but if it contained thousands of images, wouldn't it get noticeably slower, because we are loading in everything, and then discarding most of it?

Comment: If you have another source for the image tags, you could use that.

Answer (score 0):

> The list has the tags with the fewest images first, so I have to
>   reverse it:

Your assumption is incorrect, the following orders `Tags` by `ImageId` before selecting the first element, then *returning* a list in any order it chooses.

```
t.Tags.OrderBy(o => o.ImageId)
```

I'm "guessing" you want something like this, though i am not entirely sure i understand exactly what you want...

```
.Images.OrderByDescending(x => x.Tags.Count)
       .Select(t => ...)...
```

or maybe

```
ImageTags.GroupBy(x => x.ImageId)
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
         .Select(t => ...)
         .Take(10)
```